# How to print regex match

Tags: puppet, perl, regex, awk

My problme is two fold. First is printing a regex match. The second is the actual regex.

**Problem 1**: I'm trying to print the output of yum grouplist --verbose into a format that I can put into a puppet conf file. Therefore, I need to print more than just the match so sed and grep -o won't work (at least not that I know of).

Here are examples of some of the output:

```
   Maori Support (maori-support) [mi]
   Mongolian Support (mongolian-support) [mn]
   Mynamar (Burmese) Support (burmese-support) [my]
   Nepali Support (nepali-support) [ne]
```

I want all output lines that contain (*-support) to be printed out as:

```
 'maori-support': ensure => absent;
 'mongolian-support': ensure => absent;
 'burmese-support': ensure => absent;
 'nepali-support': ensure => absent;
```

I've already completed doing it manually, but I'd like to figure out how to do it as a one-line just for knowledge sake.

I've tried awk and perl to no avail. The closest I've been able to get is using perl like this:

```
 $ yum grouplist --verbose | perl -nwe 'print "$1: ensure\t=> absent;\n" if /\((.+-support)\)'
```

**Problem 2:** however, that doesn't include the single quotes into the output. There's also the problem that one of the output lines looks like this:

```
 Mynamar (Burmese) Support (burmese-support) [my]
```

The above regex matches everything from the first opening parenthesis. I don't know how to get it to start the match from the second parenthesis. I've tried modifying the regex to be non-greedy with ? but it just continues ot match (Burmese) Support (burmese-support)

Comment: what is the output you wish to see?

Comment: @glennjackman please my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum grouplist --verbose 2>/dev/null |
sed -n "s/.*(\([^)]\+-support\)).*/'\1': ensure => absent;/p"
```

Using double quotes for the sed script since you can't embed single quotes in a single quoted string.

With your sample input:

```
echo "   Maori Support (maori-support) [mi]
   Mongolian Support (mongolian-support) [mn]
   Mynamar (Burmese) Support (burmese-support) [my]
   Nepali Support (nepali-support) [ne]
" | sed -n "s/.*(\([^)]\+-support\)).*/'\1': ensure => absent;/p"
```

```
'maori-support': ensure => absent;
'mongolian-support': ensure => absent;
'burmese-support': ensure => absent;
'nepali-support': ensure => absent;
```

Comment: thanks! that was awesome. i think i understand what your regex is doing, but i'm not 100% certain. did you add the ^) class to throw out matches that include a closing parentheses so that it would start a match from the second group of parentheses?

Comment: with a string like `(a) (b) (c)`, the basic regex `(.*)` would mach the whole string. with `([^)]\+)`, you are matching an open parenthesis and a close parenthesis, and in between you have one or more character that are *not a close parentheses*. That would match `(a)` in the string. This is a technique to make your regex less "greedy".

Answer (score 0):

Another take, if you like your regexen simple

```
rev | cut -d ' ' -f2 | rev | tr '()' "'" | sed -n "/-support'/s/\$/: ensure => absent;/p"
```